# Php multiple isset check doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, isset

I have 4 inputs and they need to be filled. I made an isset test but it doesn't work. It is always showing true, but all inputs aren't filled and this php is for registering. Can you help me? Sorry for my bad English.

```
<?php
    require('config.php');
    Error_reporting(-1);
    if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){
            $username= $_POST['username'];
            $iname= $_POST['iname'];
            $email= $_POST['email'];
            $pass= $_POST['pass'];
            $pass1= $_POST['pass1'];
                if (isset ($_POST['username']['iname']['email']['pass']['pass1'])){
            /*$username= $_POST['username'];
            $iname= $_POST['iname'];
            $email= $_POST['email'];
            $pass= $_POST['pass'];
            $pass1= $_POST['pass1'];*/
                if ($pass1 == $pass){
                    $username= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $username);
                    $iname= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $iname);
                    $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
                    $pass= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $pass);
                    $pass1= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $pass1);
                    $pass= md5($pass);
                    $check="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
                    $rs = mysqli_query($link,$check);
                    $checker = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
                        if ($checker['username']  == $username)
                        {
                            echo "Username is already taken";
                            exit();
                        }
                    $insert = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `iname`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$iname', '$email', '$pass')";
                    $query = mysqli_query ($link, $insert) or die("Query error");
    //"INSERT INTO users ('id', 'username', 'iname', 'email', 'pass') VALUES ('NULL, '{$username}', '{$iname}', '{$email}', '{$pass}')"
                }else{
                    echo "Passwords doesnt match";
                }
            }else{
                echo "Fill all areas";

            }
    }else{



    }

?>
```

I tested all answers in the comments, but none of them works! I don't understand why it doesn't work!

Comment: Do not use deprecated function `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: Does this question *really* need all of that code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
if (isset ($_POST['username'], $_POST['iname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass'], $_POST['pass1'])){
 //your code
}
```

this condition will return `true` only if all arguments to `isset()` are set and do not contain `null`.

**Note:** Instead of checking only for `isset` you should check this for **empty** also.

Like following:

```
if (isset ($_POST['username'], $_POST['iname'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['pass'], $_POST['pass1']) && !empty($_POST['username']. $_POST['iname']. $_POST['email']. $_POST['pass']. $_POST['pass1'])){
     //your code
    }
```

Comment: when you send form, everytime it will be set! you have to check with function `empty`...

Comment: You are correct but OP wants to check isset only. By the way i have updated answer @Legionar

Comment: but you know, it will not work as he need to be working... when you leave that fields empty, it will continue, but it should not

Comment: Sure @Legionar I think updated answer has enough details for OP.

Comment: @Manwal You started off using commas as seperators, then using dots; probably why the OP says it doesn't work.

Comment: @Manwal I guess the OP has changed his/her mind. Now has accepted your answer. Cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have used comma `,` inside `isset` and dot `.` inside empty. Which is correct syntax.

Comment: @Manwal Well I for one have learned something today :) cheers +1 btw

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
if (isset ($username, $iname, $email, $pass,$pass1))
```

instead...

Comment: This makes the most sense because of the reuse of the users already set variables. No need to hardcode the `Post` values, and he uses these variables throughout the rest of his code. +1

Comment: when you send form, everytime it will be set! you have to check with function `empty`...

Comment: @Legionar you're right. I didn't even consider the form fact.

Comment: Not really @Legionar. PHP's isset only returns TRUE for not null values.... http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: try to send form, if you dont fill input fields, it will be not null, it will be empty, and `isset` will not work!

Comment: @Legionar you may actually be right... And never mind the -3, some people are rushing to conclusions....

Answer (score 0):

```
require('config.php');
Error_reporting(-1);
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){
        $username= $_POST['username'];
        $iname= $_POST['iname'];
        $email= $_POST['email'];
        $pass= $_POST['pass'];
        $pass1= $_POST['pass1'];
        if (!empty($username) and !empty($iname) and !empty($email) and !empty($pass) and !empty($pass1)){

            if ($pass1 == $pass){
                $username= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $username);
                $iname= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $iname);
                $email= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
                $pass= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $pass);
                $pass1= mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $pass1);
                $pass= md5($pass);
                $check="SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
                $rs = mysqli_query($link,$check);
                $checker = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs);
                    if ($checker['username']  == $username)
                    {
                        echo "Username is already taken";
                        exit();
                    }
                $insert = "INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `iname`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$iname', '$email', '$pass')";
                $query = mysqli_query ($link, $insert) or die("Query error");
//"INSERT INTO users ('id', 'username', 'iname', 'email', 'pass') VALUES ('NULL, '{$username}', '{$iname}', '{$email}', '{$pass}')"
            }else{
                echo "Passwords doesnt match";
            }
        }else{
            echo "Fill all areas";

        }
}else{



}
```

Answer (score -3):

Best way to be sure is use it separately:

```
if(isset($_POST["username"]) and isset($_POST["email"]) and.... )
```

Comment: when you send form, everytime it will be set! you have to check with function `empty`...